# Splitting one large class into several subclasses, __init__ problems

Tags: python, class, methods, instantiation

I'm having trouble with a very large class, which I'm now trying to clean up and split into subclasses. However my largest problem atm is to set up the right init methods, in order to make functions callable among the various subclasses.
The idea is to have one Ui_MainWindow class, which is handling the gui processes. Another TextMessage class that is dealing with the AT Commands and a third MessageBoxes class, which is handling all the error messages. How would I need to make the right init method for all the attributes in the setupUi function? There lies my biggest problem.
Thank you very much in advance.
The large class is this here:

```
    ALPHA = string.ascii_letters

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(503, 486)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 477, 391))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayout_2.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_2.setDisabled(True)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton.setChecked(True)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.widget)
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit2.setObjectName("lineEdit2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_path) #connect add xls button with function get_path
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 2, 1, 2, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label2.setObjectName("label2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.send_sms) #send sms function
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.line, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.connect_phone) #connect add xls button with function get_path
        self.plainTextEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_2")
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setDisabled(True)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit_2, 4, 1, 2, 1)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.widget)
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.progressBar, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.widget)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.checkBox, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 503, 27))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.radioButton.toggled['bool'].connect(self.lineEdit.setEnabled)
        self.radioButton.toggled['bool'].connect(self.lineEdit2.setDisabled)
        self.radioButton_2.toggled['bool'].connect(self.lineEdit.setDisabled)
        self.radioButton_2.toggled['bool'].connect(self.lineEdit2.setEnabled)
        self.radioButton.toggled['bool'].connect(self.pushButton.setDisabled)
        self.radioButton_2.toggled['bool'].connect(self.pushButton.setEnabled)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.plainTextEdit.textChanged.connect(self.bam)

    def bam(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    text = self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText()
        self.label2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", str(len(text))+"/160"))
    if len(text) > 160:
            root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(text[:160])
        cursor = self.plainTextEdit.textCursor()
        cursor.setPosition(self.plainTextEdit.document().characterCount() - 1)
        self.plainTextEdit.setTextCursor(cursor)
        tkMessageBox.showwarning("No Way!", "Keep it low, 160chrs max")
        root.destroy()
        root.mainloop()
        return

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Kotti&Co Mobilizer"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Single SMS"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SMS to Contacts"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add .xls"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Message Text"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send it!"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Connect Phone"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Status Report"))

    def get_path(self, MainWindow): 
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Kotti Kontaktliste",filetypes = (("excel files","*.xls"),("excel files", "*.xlsx"),("csv files","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
    if not file_path:
        return None
    else:
        self.lineEdit2.insert(file_path)

    def __init__(self, recipient="+491749449785", message="TextMessage.content not set."):
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.content = message

    def setRecipient(self, number):
        self.recipient = number

    def setContent(self, message):
        self.content = message

    def disconnectPhone(self):
        self.ser.close()

    def connect_phone(self):
    try:
        self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',
                    460800,
                    timeout=5,
                    xonxoff = False,
                    rtscts = False,
                    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
                    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
                    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
            #s = input('Enter AT command --> ')
            #print ('AT command = ' + s)
            self.ser.write(bytes('AT+CGMI' + '\r\n'))
            self.ser.timeout = 1
            self.ser.write('AT+CGMM' + '\r\n')
            self.ser.timeout = 1
            response = self.ser.read(999)
            print(response)
            self.lineEdit_2.setText(response)

    except serial.SerialException:
        self.lineEdit_2.setText("could not connect to phone")
        return None

    def check_phone(self):
        self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 
                     460800, 
                     timeout=5, 
                     xonxoff = False,   
                     rtscts = False, 
                     bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, 
                     parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, 
                     stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

    def sendMessage(self):
        self.ser.write('ATZ\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write('AT+CMGF=1\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write('''AT+CMGS="''' + self.recipient + '''"\r''')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write(self.content + "\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write(chr(26))
        time.sleep(2)

    def sms_report(self):
        self.ser.write('AT+CMEE=2\r')
        self.ser.timeout = 3
        time.sleep(1)
        self.response2 = self.ser.read(999)
        print(self.response2)
    self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText(self.lineEdit.text()+'\nmessage sent successfully'+self.response2())

    def send_sms(self):
        check = self.radioButton.isChecked()
        if check == True: #single sms use
            if not self.lineEdit.text():
                root = tk.Tk()
                root.withdraw()
                tkMessageBox.showwarning("Phone Number Missing!", "Please enter a valid phone number")
                root.destroy()
                root.mainloop()
                return
            if not self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText():
                root = tk.Tk()
                root.withdraw()
                tkMessageBox.showwarning("Message Missing!", "Please enter a text message")
                root.destroy()
                root.mainloop()
                return
            else:
                try:
                    sms = Ui_MainWindow(str(self.lineEdit.text()), str(self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText().encode('ISO-8859-1')))
                    sms.check_phone()
                    sms.sendMessage()
                    repo = self.checkBox.isChecked()
                    if repo == True:
                        sms.sms_report()

                    else:
                        self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText(self.lineEdit.text()+'\nmessage sent successfully')
                    sms.disconnectPhone()
                except serial.SerialException:
                    root = tk.Tk()
                    root.withdraw()
                    tkMessageBox.showwarning("NO GSM Connected!", "Plug in your mobile device")
                    root.destroy()
                    root.mainloop()
    else: #sms to contact sheet
        if not self.lineEdit2.text():
            root = tk.Tk()
            root.withdraw()
            tkMessageBox.showwarning("No contact sheet!", "Please add path to contact file")
            root.destroy()
            root.mainloop()
            return
        if not self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText():
            tkm.missing_message()
        else:
            try:
               with open(str(self.lineEdit2.text().encode('utf-8'))) as f:
                if str(self.lineEdit2.text().encode('utf-8')).endswith("csv"): #check whether the file is a .csv file or anything else
                        reader2 = csv.reader(f)
                    reader2.next()
                    linecount = len(zip(*reader2)[0])
                    f.seek(0)
                    reader = csv.reader(f)
                    reader.next()
                    #linecount = len(open(self.lineEdit2.text()).readlines())
                    counter = 0
                    count_all = 0
                        for i, (row) in enumerate(reader):
                        #print (row[0])
                        if not row[0] or row[0].startswith(tuple(ALPHA)): #avoid empty lines
                            counter += 1
                                continue
                        print (row[0])
                        sms = Ui_MainWindow("+491793288636", str(self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText().encode('utf-8')))
                        sms.check_phone()
                        sms.sendMessage()
                        count_all +=1
                        sms.disconnectPhone()
                        self.progressBar.setValue((count_all)*(100/(linecount-counter)))
                        if count_all == linecount-counter:
                            self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText('list completed')
                            self.progressBar.setValue(100)
                        else:
                            self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText(str(count_all)+'/'+str(linecount-counter)+'\n'+str(row[0])+'\nmessage sent successfully')
                else: #get the shit done for xls or xlsx files, converting them into data.csv
                    x =  xlrd.open_workbook(self.lineEdit2.text()) #hope that works in windoofs
                    worksheet = x.sheet_by_index(0)
                    csvfile = open('data.csv', 'wb')
                        writecsv = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

                        for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
                            writecsv.writerow(worksheet.row_values(rownum))
                    csvfile.close()
                    time.sleep(2)
                    with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
                            reader2 = csv.reader(f)
                        reader2.next()
                        linecount = len(zip(*reader2)[0])
                        f.seek(0)
                        reader = csv.reader(f)
                        reader.next()
                        print(linecount)
                        counter = 0
                        count_all = 0
                            for i, (row) in enumerate(reader):
                            #print (row[0])
                            if not row[0] or row[0].startswith(tuple(ALPHA)): #avoid empty lines
                                counter += 1
                                    continue
                            print (row[0])
                            sms = TextMessage("+491793288636", str(self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText().encode('utf-8')))
                            sms.check_phone()
                            sms.sendMessage()
                            count_all +=1
                            sms.disconnectPhone()
                            self.progressBar.setValue((count_all)*(100/(linecount-counter)))
                            if count_all == linecount-counter:
                                self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText('list completed')
                                self.progressBar.setValue(100)
                            else:
                                self.plainTextEdit_2.setPlainText(str(count_all)+'/'+str(linecount-counter)+'\n'+str(row[0])+'\nmessage sent successfully')
            except serial.SerialException:
                root = tk.Tk()
                root.withdraw()
                tkMessageBox.showwarning("NO GSM Connected!", "Plug in your mobile device")
                root.destroy()
                root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I tried to do for the other classes so far was something like:

```
lml = Ui_MainWindow()

class MessageBoxes():

    def missing_phone_number(self):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    tkMessageBox.showwarning("Phone Number Missing!", "Please enter a valid phone number")
    root.destroy()
    root.mainloop()
    return
    def missing_message(self):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    tkMessageBox.showwarning("Message Missing!", "Please enter a text message")
    root.destroy()
    root.mainloop()
    return

class TextMessage():

    def __init__(self, recipient="+491749449785", message="TextMessage.content not set."):
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.content = message

    def missing_phone_number(self): 
        tkm = MessageBoxes()
```

But I always get problems with attributes in the Ui_MainWindow class such as: `AttributeError: Ui_MainWindow instance has no attribute 'lineEdit'`

Comment: Dividing a class up into subclasses isn't a common reason for creating derived class in Object Oriented Programming—it's usually done to specialize the base class—so it will be difficult to provide advice.

Comment: Is the indenting in your code the same as the indenting you've provided here? It looks like you may have made a copying error. If so, your indentation is wrong. You are calling members before they have been assigned, so they won't exist.

Comment: Do you mean by now in the TextMessage class? Or generally?

Comment: Please, beware of identation when pasting code here. It is not just a pretty thing that can be rght 95% of the time, and at random the other 5%. It is the code Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build your divided-classes - letś call them "mixin classes" in a way they work colabortively.

In Python, that is easily achieved using the `super` built-in. 
You have to write the  `__init__` method (and possibly others - if they exist across all classes) to take arbitrary keywoard parameters, consume what they use, and call the other classes `__init__` using super. If all mixins do that, (and you have no method or attribut namign conflict), you can build arbitrarily large classes with any number os mixins.

```
class Base(object):
     pass

class M1(Base):
     """ Methods responsible for foo-things"""
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          self.foo_param1 = kwargs.pop("foo_param1")
          self.foo_param2 = kwargs.pop("foo_param2")
          super(M1, self).__init__(**kwargs)

     # define specific foo methods here:

# repeat for other mixins:

    class M2(Base):
        ...

    class M3(base):
        ...

# declare your main class:

class UI_Main(M1, M2, M3, ...):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super(Ui_Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

(And you really should be using Python3.x, in which case, yu can jus use `super().__init__(**kwargs)`, wihtout hardcoding the current class name.)